# Debugger cannot attach when using chrome profiles

Tags: vscode-debugger

I am using multiple chrome profiles for various scenarios.
I have a launch.json as follows:

```
{
  "type": "pwa-chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Custom Profile",
  "url": "http://localhost:4000/index.html?scale=.5&play=HIMSS2022&tb=1&offline=true",
  "breakOnLoad": true,
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "userDataDir": false,
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "--profile-directory=CustomProfile",
    "http://localhost:4000/index.html"
  ],
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
    "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*",
    "/./*": "${webRoot}/*",
    "/src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
    "/*": "*",
    "/./~/*": "${webRoot}/node_modules/*"
  }
},
```

If I launch with no other Chrome windows open the debugger attaches.
If I open Chrome (with a different profile or default) then the debugger fails to attach, yielding an alert `Unable to attach to browser` with Open 'launch.json' and Cancel buttons

Is there some attribute I need to add to the config, or is this just not possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure what the bot doesn't understand, but...
In Windows 10...
•Create a simple javascript web project in VS Code using webpack dev server
•Open Chrome from the desktop shortcut or from the start menu by typing Chrome
•The launch config (above) is written to use Chrome with a specific user profile.
When it is launched, the message (described above) is shown and the VS Code debugger does not attach.
•Repeat the process above without the first step of starting chrome and the debugger attaches without issue